# Почему не работают атрибуты страницы на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании страницы не отображается ссылка на родительские страницы - что делать?

Comment: Отключите все плагины поочерёдно, смените тему на стандартную. Так найдёте источник проблемы.

Comment: Пробовал отключить плагины не помогло. очистил историю очистил кэш тоже не помогало. Тему если сменить то соответственно визуально страничку сильно искажается и нужно все заново настраивать(.

Comment: Можно конечно добавлять через ссылку страничка род.страничку ну это крайне не  удобно и еще все в памяти нужно держать а страничек много добавляю(

Comment: Это значит, что у вас тема кривая и ломает вам базовый функционал WordPress

Comment: Customify тема вроде с wordpress провереная

Comment: Если временно сменить тему на стандартную 2019 - ситуация повторяется?

Comment: ДА таже самая ситуация(

Comment: Так не бывает. По определению. Все плагины отключены, тема стандартная - и все то же самое? Не верю.

Comment: Нет в этот раз плагины не отключал сейчас попробую без них

Comment: Нет все равно не работает

Comment: Мне кажется что с хостом!

Comment: что там слетает в базе может

Comment: Хост на содержимое базы не влияет. Само слетать ничего не может.

Comment: Единственное что я вчера делал это возился с SEO настройками и потом перестало высвечиваться ссылка